How to add "virtual" editable fields to a feature class?
We have several feature classes (points and lines) on an Oracle geodatabase to which a third party tool needs two fields added.  The third party tool would need read/write to these two new fields, only.  We are restricted from adding fields to the feature classes, therefore, is there a way we can have some kind of copy of these feature classes where the two fields can be added to the copy and edited while maintaining sync with the original feature classes?  Something like a replica or a view?  Or perhaps another way to accomplish this?

What do you mean by "maintaining sync" you just explicitly said you can't alter the featureclass! Sounds like you might want a related table?

We cannot alter (add two fields) to the original feature class. I'm trying to figure out a way where we can have a copy/view/replica of the original feature class where we can add the two fields that the 3rd party tool can write too.  This copy would need to be in sync with the original feature class where if features are added/removed, it would be reflected in the copy.

Generally speaking and as a comment not an answer as I've not done this... You can create an "updateable view" with a join with certain restrictions in Oracles DBs even if one of the tables is read-only.  And you can "register views" with ArcGIS Enterprise GDBs.  I have no idea if you can successfully register and use an updatable view in ArcGIS clients though...
